# Displaying dynamic data in a Grid View

Tags: c#

I want to display data in a grid view by dynamically inserting data from textboxes in a database , on click of a button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string Name = TextBox1.Text;
        //string Summary = TextBox2.Text;


        //Inserts the FirstName variable into the db-table
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table2 (Name,Summary) Values ('" + TextBox1.Text + "' , '" + TextBox2.Text + "');",conn);
        MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table2", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            //GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            // GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

I am not getting any error while running this code but it is not showing any data in the grid view

Answer (score 1):

You have to give datasource as a datatable instead of dataset.

eg:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table2", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: It's giving me error in the line GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: After removing that line , it's giving the following error

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.

Comment: @Ananya Is it Web application or windows application?

Comment: I think you try to bind data to data grid using sqldatasource from design side as well as using c# code from code behind side.

You have to do this for solving your error..

1) You need to chose one way to bind the grid
2) if it is from code behind means using c# code then remove the datasourceid property from grid view from design view of grid
like this

Hide   Copy Code
<asp:gridview id="cartData" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False" 
DataSourceID="Datasource1">
//you have to make it like this

<asp:gridview id="cartData" runat="server" autogeneratecolumns="False">

Answer (score 0):

Apart from uncommenting those lines of code you need to set the Datasource to the datatable that has been populated not the DataSet...

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

On a separate note your initial query is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks - you should never concatenate user input to form SQL queries, use Parameterised Queries instead e.g.

```
    SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table2 (Name,Summary) Values (@tb1, @tb2);", conn);
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tb1", TextBox1.Text);
    MyCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"tb2", TextBox2.Text);
    MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You are also using a using statement with a sqlcommand that you never use

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
```

should really be

```
using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table2", conn))
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to uncomment the code where the `GridView` is getting bind to the data source, as below.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from Table2", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Aliter: Create a `DataTable` instead of a `DataSet` and fill it using the `DataAdapter`.

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Try it and let us know if this works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application. Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition.

Comment: Use DataTables, I forgot to write. ds.Tables[0]

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application. Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition. Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'. Remove one definition

Comment: Go to the .aspx page..in the <asp:GridView runat="server"..> section, you will have a DataSourceID as an attribute, delete it.

Comment: You are welcome. Anyways to prevent Sql injection, use parameterized queries.